# Adding a button next to Share and Follow to open a application page

Tags: 2013

I want to add a button like "Share" or "Follow" next to Share or Follow button.

I want button to open an application page preferably on same master page without redirect.

As visible in this picture

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a delegate control targeting the `PromotedActions` DelegateControl:

> **PromotedActions Delegate Control**
>
> The PromotedActions delegate control allows you to add your own content to the following area on a SharePoint site in the top-right
>   section of the page
>
> [..]
>
> So what does the files look like for these parts of the project?
>
> Elements.xml
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
>
>   <!-- DelegateControl reference to the PromotedActions Delegate Control -->
>   <Control ControlSrc="/_controltemplates/15/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/PromotedAction.ascx"
>            Id="PromotedActions"
>            Sequence="1" />
>
> </Elements>
> ```
>
> PromotedActions.aspx (User Control)
>
> ```
> <!-- Note: I've removed the actual Facebook-logic from this snippet for easier overview of the structure. -->
> <a title="Share on Facebook" class="ms-promotedActionButton" style="display: inline-block;" href="#">
>     <span class="s4-clust ms-promotedActionButton-icon" style="width: 16px; height: 16px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block; position: relative;">
>         <img style="top: 0px; position: absolute;" alt="Share" src="/_layouts/15/images/Zimmergren.DelegateControls/facebookshare.png"/>
>     </span>
>     <span class="ms-promotedActionButton-text">Post on Facebook</span>
> </a>
> ```

From [Zimmergren](http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-some-new-delegatecontrol-additions-to-the-sharepoint-2013-master-pages)

Or you could certainly accomplish it with a custom action injecting some script injecting a new element up in the Promoted Actions section